# Writing output of a python script to HTML with CGI

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have a Python script that extracts some text from a file and annotates another file, writing the results to a new file. Because the files I am annotating are ASCII, I am very restricted as to how I can annotate the text, and I would like to instead write the results to HTML so that I can annotate by changing text color in certain parts. 
The part of the text file I annotate is just a string of characters (e.g. ACTFNKJLKD), which occurs repeatedly in the text file I am reading from.  The part of the program that finds the string, updates is as follows:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"     #header of cgi file


file1 = motif_file.readlines()
file2 = align_file_rmode.readlines() 

for line in file2: 
   for item in file1:      # "item" is the string sequence that occurs in the text file
      item = item.strip().upper()   
      if item in line:

     line = line.replace(item, 'REPLACE ITEM BY BLUE FONT' * len(item))
     <p> <bold> item </bold> </p>
     <font color="sky blue">item</font>
     align_file_amode.write(line)
```

Is there a way to specify how to change color (e.g. blue) for the length of my item while outpute that to HTML? Is a CGI necessary for this type of job? 
I am working in Python 2.6.5

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of the last few lines in your code with HTML tags, but I think I got the gist of your question. Is there some significance I'm missing for the length of `item`, or is that just how you were trying to make the text of `item` appear highlighted in blue?

Comment: Also watch out for some gotchas in your code example: seek file1 back to the beginning (or reopen it) after each iteration of your outer loop. The indentation seems messed up: the `line = line.replace...` should be indented twice, but the `align_file_amode.write(line)` should only be indented once (as I understand it).

Comment: @Mu Mind: Thanks for the answers, the significance of len(item) is that I want the text to change color and write out to HTML, but only when the program encounters an occurrence of item (e.g. ACTFNKJLKD) and for the length of that string (so if item is 10 letters long only those 10 letters are annotated to blue, while the rest of the text remains black).

Comment: @Spyros: alright, then yes, that should be what my answer does. BTW, don't forget to accept an answer (the green check mark) if/when you're satisfied your question is answered. I notice you have a few open Q's hanging around.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I had not noticed that each answer comes with an accept button for selecting my favorite answer...will correct that, usually it is a little of each answer which that get me moving forward, but will try to tick the boxes from now on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
line = line.replace(item, "<span style=\"color:skyBlue\">"+item+"</span>")
```

This will just add a `<span>` and set the color in CSS.

Comment: @Mike: yeah, I wasn't sure if that HTML was supposed to be comments or part of the output. (You are referring to the question, not my answer, right?)

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the OP's question... I deleted the `python` tag at first b/c I thought this was a pure html question... then I saw that raw html in there and added it back

Comment: I've tried out your suggestions and I get an internal server error, guess there must be something wrong with the Apache server configuration...

Comment: @ MuMind: Hi, I just wanted to ask how the line you posted works. It does exactly what I want it to do, but I'm trying to figure out why.. Sorry if this is an overly basic question, but wouldn't you have to use an escape character for Python to know that the item is a string. In short, why doesn't "<span styple=\"color:skyBlue\"< \"+ item + \" </span>" work?

Comment: @Spyros: `item` should not appear inside a string, because it's a variable name. Think of it like this: `a = "<span style=\"color:skyBlue\">"`, `b = "</span>"`, `line = line.replace(item, a+item+b)`. In some scripting languages, like sh, the interpreter is actively looking for substitutions inside a string, but in python a string is exactly the characters you type.

Comment: @MuMind: Thanks I got it now!